# Replicate folder between two Windows servers, without DFS

Tags: windows, umbraco, replication, load-balancing, mirroring

We've got two windows servers (2012 / 2008), and I need to replicate a folder left to right between them (left pushes folder content, and right only pulls or replicates).

The problem is that i can't set up a VPN / WLAN between them, and therefore can't use DFS - which was the initial plan.

Is there any simple ways to do this, without having to go into the router / set up difficult protocols etc.?

A note: it's between two Umbraco solutions (setting up load balancing!), so it's important that it checks often for changes, so it won't use more than < 15 seconds to replicate ex. an image.

Anybody have any experience with this, or a solution to recommend? :-) Been googling for hours, without coming up with anything good.

Comment: Are the machines on separate networks then? Could you use a powershell script to do it via FTP and run it as a scheduled task?

Comment: Thanks for answering! The machines are on separate networks. The problem is that it needs to synchronize instantly. (for instance, we publish an article to the site with an image -> the image then needs to be replicated to the other server, so when someone who ends up on that server via the load-balancer,  also can view the image).

I feel like the two servers really should've had a LAN / VPN connection between them, but that's pretty expensive from our provider.

Answer (score 0):

Store the images in a CDN (Azure, Amazon, etc).  There are packages that help to push media to the CDN instead of the file system.

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/ast-azure-media-sync

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/ast-amazon-s3/